# REPLACE and SET in mysql query

Tags: mysql

According to [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)  you can replace text using REPLACE keyword.

Now look at this code extracted from OpenCart

```
<?php
class ModelToolOnline extends Model {
    public function addOnline($ip, $customer_id, $url, $referer) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online` WHERE date_added < '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')) . "'");

        $this->db->query("REPLACE INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online` SET `ip` = '" . $this->db->escape($ip) . "', `customer_id` = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', `url` = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "', `referer` = '" . $this->db->escape($referer) . "', `date_added` = '" . $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . "'");
    }
}
?>
```

They have Replace query with SET keyword and no WHERE condition. Now I couldn't find anything similar to this anywhere to understand whats happening in this query.

If anyone knows what is happening in this query please explain with authentic source link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are two different things. There is a [REPLACE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and a [REPLACE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html).

In the code the REPLACE statement is used. It is similar to an INSERT statement, and thus has no WHERE clause.

Here's what the documentatin says:

> [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE`
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.